# how to know which internal networking services used between azure app service(application) and azure database service?

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-application-insights, azure-virtual-network

I have created dependency graph(between application and database ) of services with help of azure application-insights service map but I want to know about used other networking services between app service(application) and database ?
please help

Answer (score 0):

It depends upon what networking services you have between your app service and DB.

If you are using Azure SQL DB, the traffic will flow over the Azure Backbone and will not be a bottleneck. If you are using a SQL Server inside of a VNET, it could be hitting any devices that you have configured.

If you would like to drill more into those services, you will need to see how those services are monitored. If you would like those services to appear on your Application Map when they don't, You can [Leave your Feedback Here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/357324-application-insights)!